# Google Chrome extension reloader

Tags: google-chrome

I'm building this Google Chrome extension and I find it a nuisance to have to constantly go to the `Extensions` page and reload the extension I'm working on every time I make a code change. Is there a "developer mode" that automatically reloads chosen extensions for me?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30427908/how-can-i-reload-my-chrome-extension-by-javascript/56586034#56586034

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a newly-saved version of a file isn't being picked up, try disabling the cache via:
**Developer Tools > Cog/gear icon in the corner > Network > Disable cache.**

Also, if you're editing your extension's background page but don't want go through the normal reloading kerfuffle, inspect the background page and keep its Developer Tools window open. Then, to quickly reload the background page, just focus the Dev Tools window and press Ctrl+R (or Command+R).