# How can I reload my chrome extension by javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make that if you press a button in the popup window in my chrome extension, it will reload the extension. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found [this method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-reload), which does exactly what I want:

```
chrome.runtime.reload();
```